# docker swarm for bare metal : ubuntu

Tags: docker, docker-machine, docker-swarm

looking for docker support for bare metal so that it can join the swarm cluster.

Could possibly be a docker machine, so that integration with docker swarm is easily possible.

Tried a lot but couldn't find a possible solution.

Comment: Did you mean you need a guide for installing Docker and Docker Swarm on Bare metal Ubuntu?

Comment: yes .. not getting success after few days ..

Comment: I think that you should show what you tried and your error messages you met

Comment: See: https://docs.docker.com/machine/drivers/generic/

Comment: have problems in adding node to the swarm cluster ... with --swarm and --swarm-master

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at docker 12. It contains a native swarm mode which only requires docker engine to run. This hardly requires configuration, so should be very easy to setup.

Shameless plug: I wrote a blog article describing how to create a docker swarm using swarm mode on [Accidental Simplicity](http://hansthen.postach.io/post/docker-12-comes-with-native-swarm).